# on a network analyzer's measurement what's the meaning of a negative PF?

Tags: transformer, mains, power-factor-correction

on a 1 MVA transfomer, process in the place is plastics injection machinery. On the plotted data from an analyzer results in PF jumping from 0.998 to -0.997 (roughly) for all the measurement period but staying at positive when power consumption decreased, going deeper i could see kVAR value being negative. I just don't understand the meaning of that. or maybe the analizer was poorly connected?
Could you share your ideas o this?

Comment: Which analyzer?. Sounds like the machine has good Active PFC

Comment: Quick google search reveals that negative PF is the result of the load giving power back to the source.  In other words the source has become the load and vice versa.  I'd imagine if you had significant lead or lag it would indicate a big problem.  Motor spindown, generators or solar system feeding back to the grid *should* have negative PF.  Same as the difference between a motor and a generator.  It pretty much just depends on where you're standing when you make the observation.

Comment: @KH. Your comment seems good enough to post as an answer. Or at least the start of an answer.

Comment: Have to get in the shower and have a snack but I suppose you're right.  Felt like a comment when I started.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Analyzer is AEMC 8336, there is in fact Good PFC already installed, analyzer was installed immediately after transformer output, I guess just I can't picture negative vs positive PF, specially because I don't think there's a big enough motor so that the positive PF would immediately turn to opposite Value on spindown. KH i agree with sparky256,

Comment: Alternatively, the meter may indicate negative when the load has a leading power factor. Does it still display positive power consumption?

Comment: meter values were always positive

Comment: What model is the analyzer?

Comment: Analyzer model is AEMC 8336 according to contractor.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected from the beginning, your load Active PFC is working very well and is near unity. The polarity seems to only indicate a very minor shift in RMS current vs voltage < +/-1 degree.

This is more useful than just the absolute value method often calculated as it indicates the polarity of VAR error on the unity PFC.

What's the problem?  Harmonics?

Answer (score 0):

Power factor is defined as mean power divided by RMS current and RMS voltage,

As RMS is always positive the negative power factor means that mean power must be negative  so enegy is flowing in the unexpected direction.

Ihis could be because the plant is driving the motor and thus returning energy to the grid, regenerative braking and the like.